# mysql query yii not getting value

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i have an issue gettin' the value from a query:

```
public static function sa() {
 $resul = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('MAX(id)')->from('yii_availability')->execute();
 $got = mysql_query($result); 
 $res = $got['MAX(id)'] + 1;
 $rs='SA'.$res;

 return "{$rs}";
}
```

it always return **SA1**, but i want get the last id and after plus 1 so in this case i have the next autoincremental id from my id column.

For example: i am creating a new registry with the field SA0000005. This number is calculated getting the last autoincremental value plus 1.

thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$resul = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('MAX(id)')->from('yii_availability')->execute();
$got = mysql_query($result); // what are you even doing here
```

Apart from typos, that's not how you are supposed to use the query builder. Have you read [the documentation on the query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)?

The probable reason why you always get SA1, is because the `$got['MAX(id)']` expression is NULL. You add 1 to that. You want something [like this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryScalar-detail).

```
// returns false on no-result, MAX('id') otherwise
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('MAX(id)')->from('yii_availability')->queryScalar();
```

Comment: thanks Elias, i was looking many solutions but no one with queryScalar, i have the correct result now. Thanks a lot again.